# маркеры на карте

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Здравствуйте нужно сделать на google карте маркеры которые, после определенного события меняются(загораются как бы), их должно быть много, и они должны в рандомном порядке, по очереди загораться. Подскажите в каком направлении искать?

Answer (score 0):

```
var map;
function initMap(t, a) {
    // t и a точки где карту отрисовать
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        // устанавливаем стартовую точку
        center: {lat:  t || 53.8954676 , lng:  a || 27.548207},
        zoom: 8
    });
    // Создаем маркер на карте
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // Определяем позицию маркера или меняем его положение
        position: {lat:  t || 53.8954676 , lng:  a || 27.548207},
        // Указываем, где он должен появится.
        map: map,
        // иконка для маркера
        icon: 'Untitled-1.png'
    });
}
```

определяй далее событие анимации или чего либо очень подробно описано [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)